# Modifying SSL cert check Powershell script to loop through multiple sites

Tags: powershell, ssl

I'm a Powershell newb, but I am trying to write a script to check the SSL certificate expiration dates for multiple remote websites.

I found this script (http://www.zerrouki.com/checkssl/) that does what I want, but only for a single site.
I am trying to modify it to allow for multiple sites/checks, but am getting an error when I do so. I've removed all of the email functionality from the script as I'll be using another to tool to alert on expiring certs. And I've hardcoded the URLs to check.

```
 <#
    Modified from Fabrice ZERROUKI - fabricezerrouki@hotmail.com Check-SSL.ps1
#>
$WebsiteURLs= @("URL1.com","URL2.com","URL3.com")
$WebsitePort=443
$CommonName=$WebsiteURL
$Threshold=120

foreach ($WebsiteURL in $WebsiteURLs){
Try{
    $Conn = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($WebsiteURL,$WebsitePort) 

    Try {
        $Stream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($Conn.GetStream())
        $Stream.AuthenticateAsClient($CommonName) 

        $Cert = $Stream.Get_RemoteCertificate()

        $ValidTo = [datetime]::Parse($Cert.GetExpirationDatestring())

        Write-Host "`nConnection Successfull" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host "Website: $WebsiteURL"

        $ValidDays = $($ValidTo - [datetime]::Now).Days

        if ($ValidDays -lt $Threshold)
        {
        Write-Host "`nStatus: Warning (Expires in $ValidDays days)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "CertExpiration: $ValidTo`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host "`nStatus: OK" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host "CertExpiration: $ValidTo`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
    }
    Catch { Throw $_ }
    Finally { $Conn.close() }
    }
    Catch {
            Write-Host "`nError occurred connecting to $($WebsiteURL)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host "Website: $WebsiteURL"
            Write-Host "Status:" $_.exception.innerexception.message -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host ""

}
}
```

When I run this (with valid sites in the $WebsiteURLs variable) every site returns: Status: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

If I only put one site in the $WebsiteURLs variable and remove the foreach function it runs ok.

Any idea what I can do to make this loop through each site in the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies here:

```
$WebsiteURLs= @("URL1.com","URL2.com","URL3.com")
$WebsitePort=443
$CommonName=$WebsiteURL
```

When you call `$Stream.AuthenticateAsClient($CommonName)` it doesn't work, because `$CommonName=$WebsiteURL` is setting `$commonName` to `null`. When you remove the loop I assume you did as I did and changed `$WebsiteURLs` to `$WebsiteURL` so then you had a value to assign `$CommonName`.

If you move the declaration of `$CommonName` to within your loop it works.

```
$WebsiteURLs= @("URL1.com","URL2.com","URL3.com")
$WebsitePort=443
$Threshold=120

foreach ($WebsiteURL in $WebsiteURLs){
$CommonName=$WebsiteURL
Try{
    $Conn = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($WebsiteURL,$WebsitePort) 

    Try {
        $Stream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($Conn.GetStream())
        $Stream.AuthenticateAsClient($CommonName) 

        $Cert = $Stream.Get_RemoteCertificate()

        $ValidTo = [datetime]::Parse($Cert.GetExpirationDatestring())

        Write-Host "`nConnection Successfull" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host "Website: $WebsiteURL"

        $ValidDays = $($ValidTo - [datetime]::Now).Days

        if ($ValidDays -lt $Threshold)
        {
        Write-Host "`nStatus: Warning (Expires in $ValidDays days)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "CertExpiration: $ValidTo`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host "`nStatus: OK" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host "CertExpiration: $ValidTo`n" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        }
    }
    Catch { Throw $_ }
    Finally { $Conn.close() }
    }
    Catch {
            Write-Host "`nError occurred connecting to $($WebsiteURL)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host "Website: $WebsiteURL"
            Write-Host "Status:" $_.exception.innerexception.message -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host ""

}
}
```